# How do I play an audio file using C++ in Linux?

Tags: c++, c

I am coding this C++ program. I want to play an audio clip and the format doesn't matter. It's just I wrote *Hello, World!*, the most basic program of any language, but instead of showing "Hello, World!" on the terminal screen I want a pre-recorded hello audio clip to be played. But how do I play an audio clip using C++?

I'm using Kubuntu, and a sample program showing a solution will be preferred.

Comment: Although it might seem to conceptually follow from `hello world`, playing audio is really a lot more complicated - you'll need to deal with external libraries to decode the input file and send it to the hardware, and there are lots of possible error conditions to consider. See, eg, the GStreamer multimedia hello world example http://docs.gstreamer.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=327735 - C rather than C++, and video rather than audio, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `canberra-gtk-play -f path_to_audio_file` to play .ogg, .wav files e.g.:

```
canberra-gtk-play -f audio.ogg
```

would play audio.ogg in the local directory.

The `system()` function can be used to call system shell commands from within a C/C++ program. e.g.:

```
int main()
{
  system("canberra-gtk-play -f audio.ogg");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect `canberra-gtk-play` isn't installed by default in Kubuntu, and in any case using `system()` might be cheating a little...

Comment: Yes it a little cheat... I agree...

Comment: In fairness I should say that it does solve the problem as written though.

Answer (score 2):

I've made an MP3 player all in C for my Raspberry Pi. I followed instructions from here:

http://hzqtc.github.io/2012/05/play-mp3-with-libmpg123-and-libao.html

This will only play MP3 files at the moment, but I plan on adding [Ogg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg) playback as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I'm helpful, because I'm not quite sure myself and haven't tried it yet; try [ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page), and read this seemingly helpful article on [Introduction to Sound Programming with ALSA](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6735), I'm pretty sure you would get what you want.